# How do I retrieve ebay products with UPC code?

Tags: php, rest, ebay-api

I have a UPC for a digital camera (Canon EOS 350D) and I would like to find products on ebay that match this UPC. I have read the API documentation and tried the following:

http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=MYAPPID&siteid=0&ProductID.Value=8714574585628&ProductID.Type=UPC&version=773

But, this doesn't give me the restuls even though there is a result when I search that UPC on ebay.co.uk

How can I get the listings that match this UPC to return?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be using the Finding API -> FindItemsAdvanced Call.
Here is an example of a call for what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<findItemsAdvancedRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <descriptionSearch>true</descriptionSearch>
    <paginationInput>
        <entriesPerPage>10</entriesPerPage>
    </paginationInput>
    <keywords>753182925158</keywords>
</findItemsAdvancedRequest>
```

Of course, this is not the only way. But I find it to be the easiest.